# UTF8 Trouble while migrating from MSSQL to MySQL with MySQL Workbench

Tags: sql-server, mysql, migration, mysql-workbench, character-set

I am tasked with migrating part of our database from an on-site MSSQL server to an Amazon RDS MySQL. This will be my first attempt with a database migration, so I am doing a dry run from our MSSQL server to a locally installed instance of MySQL using MySQL Workbench. Local install MySQL Workbench version 6.3. MySQL Server version 5.7

- Error generated: `Inserting Data: Incorrect string value: '\xA0\xA0 I-D...' for column 'Address1' at row 77` while performing bulk data transfer.

  - This happens twice in the same table (two different rows). All other tables are successful.

*Symptoms:*

- On the Object Migration -> Manual Editing -> Column Mappings screen, I see a list of migration messages/warnings.

  - On columns that go from source VARCHAR/NVARCHAR to VARCHAR, I get "Collation SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS migrated to utf8_general_ci. Same for Char to Char.
  - On columns that go from source BIT to TINYINT(1), I get "Source column type BIT was migrated to TINYINT(1)

*Settings:*

- Source Selection  is MSSQL Server, ODBC (Free TDS)

  - Advanced tab has "Driver sends Unicode data as UTF-8" checked. Required for Free TDS
- Target Selection is local MySQL. Connection method is Standard(TCP/IP)

I have read [THIS](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4) article which seems quite promising, but I am not sure how to implement step 3 as it is a migration and when I get to the "Create Schemas" step, it says it will drop the schema and recreate anew if it already exists.

- All the indexes on this database are on small columns, so the 3-bit to 4-bit utf8 will not be an issue for indexes.
- As far as "Modify connection, client, and server character sets" to be utf8mb4, I cannot even find the file to modify. I went to MySQL Server 5.7/my-default.ini and changed it to include

  ```
  [client]
  default-character-set = utf8mb4

  [mysql]
  default-character-set = utf8mb4

  [mysqld]
  character-set-client-handshake = FALSE
  character-set-server = utf8mb4
  collation-server = utf8mb4_unicode_ci
  ```

  as requested, but my variables still look like the below picture, so that is obviously not the right file. Plus, will I actually have access to this on the Amazon RDS instance?

[image]

Any thoughts?

Comment: see my answer in https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/152644/incorrect-string-value-while-migrating-from-mssql-to-mysql-with-workbench

Answer (score 1):

Hex `A0` probably came from a Word document, where it is a "hard space".

It appears that you did not specify that the source was 'latin1' and the destination is 'utf8'.  Otherwise, `A0` should have turned into `C2A0`.  That seems correct.  However, this seems incorrect: "Driver sends Unicode data as UTF-8".  Or perhaps just inconsistent with "Collation SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS migrated to utf8_general_ci".  Did you do anything in ODBC to tell it to convert latin1 to utf8?

You have an inconsistency -- some places you mention utf8, some mention utf8mb4.  Outside MySQL, there is only "utf8" (or "UTF-8"), but inside MySQL there is a difference between utf8 and utf8mb4.  If you intend to handle Chinese or Emoji, go with utf8mb4.

Answer (score 0):

You need to restart mysql to see the changes you made.

Go to Task manager and click services tab.

In the services tab, you can find mysql to restart..