# "Incorrect string value" while migrating from MSSQL to MySQL with Workbench

Tags: mysql, migration, mysql-workbench, utf-8

I got the task to migrate our MSSQL database into a MySQL database.
Therefore I am using the recent version of MySQL Workbench and FreeTDS Driver.

During the migration I always get errors like this:

```
ERROR: `dbo`.`emails_text`:Inserting Data: Incorrect string value: '\xA0</td>...' for column 'description' at row 1
ERROR: `dbo`.`prospect_lists`:Inserting Data: Incorrect string value: '\xFCrs MB...' for column 'description' at row 4
ERROR: `dbo`.`campaigns`:Inserting Data: Incorrect string value: '\xFChrung...' for column 'name' at row 24
```

I assume that utf8 is the troublemaker but I couldn't find any solution to my problem till now.

Answer (score 1):

I had to do the following:

In the source configuration (ODBC FreeTDS), tab "Advanced", I set:

```
TDS_VERSION=7.2;ClientCharset=UTF-8
```

and check "Driver sends Unicode data as UTF-8".
(for more info in http://www.freetds.org/userguide/odbcconnattr.htm )

Then, in the target configuration, tab "Advanced", in textbox "Others" I added the following new line: (change it as you whish, always utf8* )

```
preInit=SET default_storage_engine=MYISAM,character_set_connection=utf8mb4,collation_connection=utf8mb4_spanish_ci,collation_server=utf8mb4_spanish_ci,character_set_server=utf8mb4
```

(for more info see:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-options.html
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/en/connector-cpp-connect-options.html )

Finally in the Data Copy step, in Options group check "Driver sends data already encoded as UTF-8".

Comment: If you are the same person as the OP, please merge your accounts. See: [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).

Comment: no, I'm not the same person...

Comment: thnx. The *"I had to do the following:"* got me confused! I suppose you meant you faced a similar problem ;)

Answer (score 0):

Which of these look correct for \xFC ?

```
             armscii8   2  1 'Ֆ'
cp1250, cp1256, cp1257, dec8, latin1, latin2, latin5, latin7   2  1 'ü'
               cp1251   2  1 'ь'
                cp850   2  1 '³'
                cp852   2  1 'Ř'
                greek   2  1 'ό'
         koi8r, koi8u   2  1 'Э'
                macce   2  1 'Ł'
             macroman   2  1 '¸'
       cp866, keybcs2   3  1 'ⁿ'
```

If none of them, then MSSQL is generating unknown garbage.

`\A0` is a "hard blank" in many character sets.  Some exceptions:

```
cp850, cp852, keybcs2   2  1 'á'
                cp866   2  1 'а'
         koi8r, koi8u   3  1 '═'
      macce, macroman   3  1 '†'
```

You could move forward by declaring the column in question to be `CHARACTER SET latin1` and live with the garbage until figuring out what to do.

Do you have more examples of bad characters?  Maybe a pattern will emerge.